# Why is a workflow, which is associated with a content type, not associated with a document of that content type?

Tags: workflow, content-type

We have Sharepoint 2010 and MS Word 2007.

I have the three default workflows (Collect Feedback, Approval, Collect Signatures) associated with a content type based on the document content type.

When I want to start a workflow, Sharepoint says there are no workflows available to start on this item.

Comment: Can you verify that your workflows are added to specific content type? See [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc678859.aspx#SiteCType)

Comment: Yes, I have. Does a workflow have to be associated with both the library and the content type, or is an association with the content type enough?

Comment: Association with the content type is enough. Are you sure your item content type is the same as one you associated workflow with? I did quick test and I don't see any possible issues so there is most likely some simple mistake here.

Comment: @Vedran, It is associated with the same content type, because if I make changes to the template attached to the content type, those changes appear in new documents based on that content type. Those new documents then still do not have any workflows available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason was that the three default workflows were disallowed on the Remove Workflows page. I merely allowed them again. Everything is fine now.

You get to the Remove Workflows page by going to the relevant document library, clicking Workflow Settings, selecting the applicable content type and then clicking the "Remove a workflow link".

Answer (score 0):

check this , it may help, 
It's not the same but could give you an idea.
http://spreza.blogspot.com.au/2013/05/reusable-workflow-which-is-associated.html

Comment: So not really an answer, then, just a link to your blog ;-). Seriously, you should only use Answer for actual answers to the question, and we  require disclosure of any affiliation with  products or websites. Please see [May I promote products or websites I  am affiliated with here?](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion) for guidelines.